# How can I install Ubuntu Touch on my Nook HD+? (tutorial)

Tags: ubuntu-touch, tablet

I've looked at the links on the Ubuntu website, and it seems to be confusing. There's a link for me to install the Ubuntu FS file, so I click the link, but I'm faced with too many of them. Can someone tell me what I should do? Should I try one of these, or is there a better option?

Answer (score 0):

Here. I installed ubuntu on my nook yesterday. What I did was I downloaded the right files and followed the steps on this [here](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Touch/Devices/ovation) website and it worked great! If it doesn't work. Try downloading a later version of touch.